# Can someone explain かんーわええのぅ

Tags: phrases, role-language

I was reading some comments on [this Youtube video](https://youtu.be/E9tuO9lsrXc) and this comment in particular had a bunch of likes:

かんーわええのぅ。

I looked it up and it translates as "I don't know" on Google Translate.

Can someone explain this one to me? I looked up the parts like かん on Jisho but it still doesn't make much sense. I just started learning so I'm probably just missing something basic.

Comment: What was the video about? It could be an extreme bastardization of 「かわいいな」if it involved something cute.

Comment: It was a video about a red panda. Funny that Google Translate got it so wrong.

Comment: Google translate getting it wrong is not unusual.

Answer (score 5):

> **かんーわええのぅ。。** 鼻水までもが愛おしく見える。世界いち**かわいいよ**ー。

They meant 「かわいいな。」/「かわいいなあ。」, "Wow that's cute." They wrote it in an emphatic, lengthened, and nonstandard (dialectal or classic) way. (な/なあ indicates 詠嘆/exclamation. Related post [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/80684/9831).)

(What they meant is also clear from the last part of their comment, 「かわいいよー。」)

いい often changes to ええ in western dialects. Related: [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/65899/9831) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/53231/9831).

The のぅ is the sentence-ending particle / 終助詞「のう」. See [デジタル大辞泉](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%AE%E3%81%86-596155). (Don't confuse this with [終助詞「の」](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%AE-596099).) Please see also [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12106/9831) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27433/9831). It corresponds to standard/modern な、なあ or ね、ねえ. (デジタル大辞泉 says: `近代以降は「ね」「ねえ」「なあ」が一般化し、現在では主に、方言として西日本で用いられる。`) This のう is still heard in some western dialects, but it can also sound old-fashioned and is often used as [老人語/old man's speech](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E8%80%81%E4%BA%BA%E8%AA%9E), a kind of [役割語/role language](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E5%BD%B9%E5%89%B2%E8%AA%9E) in fiction (and this may be why someone has responded to it 「おじいちゃん目線ｗ」).

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the detailed response.