# Interpreting な in 年賀状に使えるな

Tags: particle-な

A Japanese person that was born in Nagoya wrote on instagram a very short sentence: 年賀状に使えるな that I'm not able to translate. Different online translators give opposite results. The [TanoshiJapanese dictionary](https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/entry_details.cfm?entry_id=97489) doesn't help me distinguish between meanings 1) and 3).

- How would you interprete the "な" at the end of the sentence?

Comment: imperative negative

Answer (score 1):

To break it down:

年賀状 "new years card"
に "as, for, for the purpose of"
使える "can use" "be usable" -- potential form of 使う
な -- sentence ending particle (終助詞) for 詠嘆, 推量, 納得, etc.

> 年賀状に使えるな。

The な here can indicate light exclamation, conjecture, or maybe conviction. So it can mean something like:

> "It can be used as a new years card(, I think/suppose)."
> "(I think / I'm sure) I can use it as a new years card."

A few examples of this な:

> かわいいな。　Oh that's cute.
> いい天気だな。 What a nice day.
> お[腹]{なか}が[空]{す}いたな。 I feel hungry.
> 明日は晴れるな。 (I think) it'll be sunny tomorrow.

---

It cannot be negative imperative ("Don't ~~!") in your example since 使える is the potential form.

Compare:
使いな。 -- light command
使うな。 -- negative imperative

Comment: Thanks. You answer helped me to understand the difference between the two verbs I mixed up
使う to use (godan, transitive)
使える to be usefull (ichidan, intransitive)